# How to Auto Update the content of a ComboBox ItemSource when a property of an item has changed - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

How do I refresh the ComboBox ItemSource when one of the Items has changed?

I have bound the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection with some extension that allow to get the changes on an Item property via another event.

I don't wanna do a Reset inside the ObsevableCollection because that breaks my DataGrid binding.

CS Code

```
public ObjectEditor()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    EnumParametersList.CollectionItemPropertyChanged += EnumParametersList_CollectionItemPropertyChanged;
}

void EnumParametersList_CollectionItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedObservableCollection<EnumParameters>.CollectionItemPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //refresh list
}
```

Xaml Code

```
<ComboBox d:DataContext="" x:Name="EnumListCombo"  SelectedItem="{Binding EnumType}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding EnumParametersList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,3,0,0" Height="22" 
          Visibility="{Binding VariableType, Converter={StaticResource IsEnumTypeVisible}, Mode=OneWay}"
/>
```

EDIT:

I have it working when the list is binded as Dependecy Property but still the current selected don't change, only if the user change the selection back and forth

Comment: @verdesrobert ComboBox has always had a ItemsSource

Comment: @LucasLocatelli It sounds like you need to implement INotifyPropertyChange on each of your enum types and add each property to the observable collection upon load. That way if you have to change the value of one the enums then you shouldn't have to reset the itemssource

Comment: The issue really is the one that is current selected don't change the value, but the it is changed on the drop down list.

Comment: Another annoying thing is it only updates the list once, if I pull the combo box list to see the changes it don't get updated anymore.